# Out of memory because of heap memory in For loop?

Tags: java, android, heap-memory

Recently, I declare a function and I put the function in `for` loop like below:

```
 Bitmap image = ...//Do stuff to get image's bitmap, it's quite ok
 for(int i =0; i < someNumber; i++){
      image = doSomeThing(image, width, height);      
 }

 private Bitmap doSomeThing(image, width, height){
      int[] a = new int[10000];
      Bitmap bitmap = image.copy(sentBitmap.getConfig(), true);
      // Do some stuff here to process image
      ...
      return (bitmap);
 }
```

With the `for` loop argument `someNumber` is smaller than 5, my application is quite fine, otherwise, I will be `outOfMemory`. So I want to ask for a suggestion to resolve this `exception`! Can I use `System.gc()`? Or can I do something to remove ununsed memory after each loop of `for`?

Edited: Sorry, maybe I omited too much, I updated my code!

**Edited2** : If instead of `for` loop, I use call `image = doSomething(...)` for multiple times, the `exception` is no more!!

Thanks!

Comment: Do you save the reference to the new array somewhere? Otherwise I don't see why the JVM should complain instead of freeing up memory

Comment: Maybe show us more code?

Comment: Assuming the loop body does not contain anything else you omitted and you don't leak a reference of a[] to outside of doSomeThing(), you should either get the exception immediately or never. You probably overlooked something.

Comment: Use the DDMS and track the Heap before and after the loop to see if it is the loop causing it. Also, would can help if you show us what you do with a[]

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to call `image.recycle()` when you're done with it in the for loop.

Edit: Ah, I see what you're trying to do, apply multiple filters to the same image. Try this:

```
 Bitmap image = ...;
 for(int i =0; i < someNumber; i++){
      Bitmap newImage = doSomeThing(image, width, height);
      image.recycle();
      image = newImage;
 }
```

Comment: But I want to `return (bitmap)`, if I call `recycle()` I will lost everything!!

Comment: Instead of `bitmap`, better call recycle on `image` if it's not used anymore.

Answer (score 0):

On a `Java` standpoint the `System.gc()` will probably have no effect because as you run out of memory Java will clear it if it can.

Your `doSomeThing()` call is probably creating too many object for the amount of memory you have.

Either increase it and if you can't because of constraints on memory footprint, adjust your `Eden` space.

Comment: it's a question about android, I doubt it gives option to increase eden space size.